# integrating slick with lift

Tags: scala, lift, slick

I'm using lift(It's brilliant!) for a web app and am confused what to use - slick or mapper.
I have previously used mapper with an app. It works well but I found one problem. Suppose I want to query database based on multiple filters which may or may not be present I couldn't figure out a way to do that. eg.

```
class Gig extends LongKeyedMapper[Gig]{
  def primaryKeyField = id
  def getSingleton = Gig

  object id extends MappedLongIndex(this) {
    override def dbColumnName = "id"
    override def dbIndexed_? = true
  }

  object slug extends MappedString(this, 250) {
    override def dbColumnName = "slug"
    override def dbNotNull_? = true
  }

  object status extends MappedEnum(this, GigStatus) {
    override def dbColumnName = "status"
    override def dbIndexed_? = true
    override def targetSQLType(field: String) = Types.TINYINT
  }

  object title extends MappedString(this, 150) {
    override def dbColumnName = "title"
    override def uniqueFieldId = Full("gig_title")
    override def dbNotNull_? = true
    override def validations = valMinLen(5, "Please add a proper title.") _ :: valMaxLen(150, "Title can not exceed 150 characters") _ ::  super.validations
  }

  object description extends MappedText(this) with StringValidators{
    override def dbColumnName = "description"
    override def uniqueFieldId = Full("gig_desc")
    override def dbNotNull_? = true

    protected def valueTypeToBoxString(in: String): Box[String] = {
      Full(this.is)
    }

    protected def boxStrToValType(in: Box[String]): String = {
      in openOr null
    }

    def maxLen = 200
    override def validations = valMinLen(30, "Please add a proper description.") _ :: Nil
  }

  object locked extends MappedBoolean(this) {
    override def dbColumnName = "locked"
  }

  object amount extends MappedDouble(this) {
    override def dbColumnName = "amount"
    override def uniqueFieldId = Full("gig_amount")
    override def dbNotNull_? = true
  }

  object category extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, Category) {
    override def dbColumnName = "category"
    override def uniqueFieldId = Full("gig_category")
    override def dbNotNull_? = true

    override def validations = categoryExists _ :: super.validations

    def categoryExists(id: Long): List[FieldError] = {
      Category.findByKey(id) match {
        case Full(cat) => Nil
        case _ => List(FieldError(this, "Invalid category selected"))
      }
    }
  }

  object createdOn extends MappedDateTime(this) {
    override def dbColumnName = "created_on"
  }

  object updatedOn extends MappedDateTime(this) {
    override def dbColumnName = "updated_on"
  }

  object createdBy extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, User) {
    override def dbColumnName = "created_by"
  }

  object updatedBy extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, User) {
    override def dbColumnName = "updated_by"
  }

  def canApply: Boolean = {
    User.currentUser.map(user => user.provider_? && !user.id.is.equals(createdBy.is)) openOr false
  }

  def myUrl = "/gigs/"+id.is+"/"+slug.is

  def editUrl = "/gigs/"+id.is+"/edit"

  def unlockUrl = "/payment?id="+this.id.is+"&type=gig&action=unlock"

  def hasAnyBidsByUser(user: User): Boolean = {
    Bid.get(this, user).size match {
      case 0 => false
      case _  => true
    }
  }

  def locked_? = this.locked.is

  def bidsCount = Bid.getBidsCount(this)

  def isOwner(user: User): Boolean = user.id.is.equals(this.createdBy.is)
}
```

Suppose I want to query gigs with amount=10 and title = 'Sample'. Either or none of which could be present. When I used hibernate earlier while working in java I used to add to criteria based on conditions if amount!=null add amount to criteria and if title!=null add title to criteria. I did this using native sql in mapper using `findAllByInsecureSql` I don't know if it was the best way or not.

Currently I'm trying out slick with lift. I couldn't find any resources on how to get it working. Can someone point me in right direction as to what should I use. Mapper or Slick and any good resources to integrating slick with lift.

Comment: Another option that I am not sure if you've considered is Squeryl http://squeryl.org/. I've not used Slick with Lift, so I can't answer that part of your question, but I have used Squeryl and you should be able to accomplish what you are looking to do with that.